# How to replace the value of an input if it is less than a minimum value established?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I make this calculation in javascript, and how do I do it so that the final result has a minimum value of 3500?

```html
<div id="multiplicar-fijos">
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="multiplicando-fijos" value="" onChange="multiplicar();" />
    <input type="text" id="multiplicador-fijos" class="" value="75" onChange="multiplicar();" readonly="readonly" />
    <input type="text" id="resultado_1" class="monto" onkeyup="sumar();" readonly="readonly" /><span id="Costo"></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="multiplicando-itinerantes" value="" onChange="multiplicar2();" />
    <input type="text" id="multiplicador-itinerantes" class="" value="275" onChange="multiplicar2();" readonly="readonly" />
    <input type="text" id="resultado_2" class="monto" onkeyup="sumar();" readonly="readonly" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>El resultado es: </span> <input type="text" id="Total" onchange="cambio(this)" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please provide your multiplicar functions

Comment: Where is the logic that makes the total?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply take [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) with the value and the wanted minimum.

```
Math.max(value, 3500)
```